# Python code to fill and submit Stulish Form

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm trying to write a Python code to submit a simple form.

http://stulish.com/soumalya01

[Edit : http://travelangkawi.com/soumalya01/

When you use this link it returns a different page on form submit. Is good for debugging]

Any code would do

Tried both mechanize and mechanical soup. Both are unable to handle the text fields. It does not have a name only ID. But we are unable to get the element by ID

Any Code would do as long as it works. (Fill ABC in the text box and hit submit)

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Are you asking for a random python code or what? And what does it have to do with Stulish? Also, please clarify the requirements for the code you are asking.

Comment: It needs to go to the stulish link post a message and submit the form... (Click ok).

Comment: got it to work thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I just followed the documentations of `mechanize`. See sample code below:

```
from mechanize import Browser


br = Browser()

br.open('http://stulish.com/soumalya01')


br.select_form(nr=0)

form.set_all_readonly(False) #add this

br.form.set_value('ABC', nr=1)

print(br.form.controls[1])

br.submit()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. It does seem to be working without errors but the form is actually not getting submitted.

Comment: what do you mean not getting submitted @SoumalyaSaha

Comment: when I go to the website write ABC and click ok. I get a message in my profile. That message is not getting through when I'm running the code. Cant find what the issue is now.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. But it is still not working.

Comment: Edit : http://travelangkawi.com/soumalya01/
When you use this link it returns a different page on form submit. When I'm checking the res.read() on br.submit()..... it is still returning the original page HTML instead of the form submit page html.